# Why does my SQL query not work as I want to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a project for user administration in ASP.NET Web App (Framework 4.8). In the code have made search box where I want to be able to search for Name,EmployeeNumber and if they are Excluded or not. I use it as a filter so I do not need to scroll through all the pages in the gridview. I have tried some changes in the query but it does not seem to make a difference. I am not so familiar with these kind of SQL queries just so you know.

So I wonder if someone can simply explain to me exactly what is wrong with my query and why?

`PopulateGridView:`

```
 void PopulateGridView()
        {
            string find = "select * from TBL_USERS where (Name like '%' + @Name + '%') or (employee like '%' + @Employee + '%') and (case when excluded =1 then 'True' else 'False' end like '%false%')";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);
            comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@Employee", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@Excluded", SqlDbType.Bit, 1).Value = 1;
            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = comm;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Name");
            da.Fill(ds, "Employee");
            da.Fill(ds, "Excluded");
            gvTestUsers.DataSource = ds;
            gvTestUsers.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            
        }
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Also, why that `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` and not just `AND excluded = 0`?

Comment: what are you actually seeing, and how does that differ from what you expect? note: that last clause (with the `case when excluded`) looks very suspicious - especially if the database is case sensitive - why not just a test on `excluded=@Excluded` ? also, if `@Employee` is an employee number - you *might* want to use `=` for that, not `like`

Comment: Don't mix AND and OR without using `( )` to specify exactly what you wanted to be anded and/or orred. Be careful baking `%` into the query; it's better yto put it in the *parameter* so you can choose how to match the values. How you have it there will always do a "contains", but if you put it in the parameter,  you could do a "starts with" by sending a value of `"John%"` in the textbox. Right now if they leave the name box blank and write in the employee box they get all records anyway because `name like '%%'` is true (except for name being null)

Comment: Observation: you are executing this query ... four times? - once as a statement (`ExecuteNonQuery`), which means the results are ignored - and three times via a `DataAdapter`; what are you actually trying to do here? I genuinely don't know what you're trying to do with the `"Name"`, `"Employee"`, `"Excluded"` bit on that trio of `Fill` calls (honestly, I haven't used `DataAdapter` in something like 15 years; it is almost never the right approach to do anything)

Comment: @MarcGravell did you write Dapper to get away from them? :D

Comment: @CaiusJard even before Dapper, I would probably have just used a data-reader and a POCO, but yes, I wrote Dapper to get rid of that repetition

Comment: @Larnu I want my query to work as a filter so for example when I put a Name in the box, the gridview will show me all the users that has that Name. When I put an Employeenumber in the box, it will only show the one user with that exactly Employeenumber. When I put in either True or False in the box, the gridview will show either all the users that are Excluded or all the Users that are not Excluded. The CASE expression is meant to return all the appropriate values I guess. But as I mentioned I am not familiar with this at all and thought I could learn something.

Comment: No need to open a connection for a dataadapter, or even declare the connection and command objects; you can just pass your sql and connstr to the adapter as strings, fill once.. This whole code should be about 6 lines long

Comment: @MånsBodin you can certainly learn something.. I suspect I've already mentioned the root cause of your problem (and in tandem with Marc's comments I'd say we've sounded out pretty much every other problem in the code)

Comment: @CaiusJard re "This whole code should be about 6 lines long" -  `gvTestUsers.DataSource = con.Query<User>(@"select * from TBL_USERS where ...", new { Name = TextBox1.Text, Employee = TextBox1.Text, Excluded = true }).AsList();` - one line :)

Comment: You'll get no disagreements from me; plenty of times I'll write an answer that fixes up their broken DataAdapter stuff and then tag a mini Dapper tutorial on the end. Fantastic piece of kit, and thanks for providing it!

Comment: that stuff at the end '(case when excluded =1 then 'True' else 'False' end like '%false%')'
could you just use excluded <> 1?   
also your exclusion only applies to the employee search, not the name search.  That's because of AND have precedence over OR in its evaluation order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue appears to be the lack of parenthesis around the `OR`. It's not entirely clear what sort of filtering you want: whether you want to search for either value, or whether you want to search only for a non-empty value. You may need to adjust the conditions

Your C# code should look like this

```cs
void PopulateGridView()
{
    const string find = @"
select *
from TBL_USERS
where (Name like '%' + @Name + '%' or employee like '%' + @Employee + '%')
and excluded = @Excluded
";
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
    using(var comm = new SqlCommand(find, con))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Employee", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Excluded", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
        con.Open();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        using(var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        gvTestUsers.DataSource = dt;
        gvTestUsers.DataBind();
    }            
}
```

- Note the use of a *new* connection object, not a cached one
- Note the `using` blocks
- Note that the query string is a `const`, this makes it somewhat less likely for you to get that itch to inject data into it
- Since you only have one table, you can put it into a `DataTable`
- An adapter is only useful when you have existing data to merge with

Comment: *An adapter is only useful when you have existing data to merge with* - absolutely not true. Your `dt.Load` uses an adapter internally.. This code would be vastly simpler with an adapter

Comment: @CaiusJard Not really any simpler, because you still need to create an adapter and load into a `DataTable` or `DataSet`, so you're not saving any lines of code

Comment: but the datatable has a load method - you can go dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader()) and thus no need for a reader or a adaptor - its built into the command object.  So no real need to create a var called reader.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal yea, and you don't need any of it if you use an adapter.. but Charlieface wanted to dispose the reader, hence the `using` - and *These Decades* there are better ways all round than all this long-winded, stringly-typed crap

Comment: The extra load of EF can often cost effort and time.  Often the extra work to have and put a class between you and the data has downsides here that can't be ignored. The issue was having to create an adaptor in code - not that say ExecuteReader uses one, and that's quite a difference here. It what one has to code. In general a adaptor defined in code is only required when you  to "adapt" or modify data in the data table. If one is not to modify the data table, then rare if at all is a defined adaptor in code is required. and yet oh so many code examples have them for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

> when I put a Name in the box, the gridview will show me all the users that has that Name. When I put an Employeenumber in the box, it will only show the one user with that exactly Employeenumber

Personally I'd use different queries if e.g. the EmployeeNumber is an integer/you can tell what the user wants from what they typed. Trying to make dynamic queries where you have a bunch of parameters that are all ORred plan typically quite badly and give poor performance. [Building an SQL with a targeted where clause](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) is preferred over fudging something together with N different parameters that are ORred.

And I'd use Dapper:

```
if(!int.TryParse(TextBox.Text)) //by name
  gvTestUsers.DataSource = con.Query<User>(
    @"select * from TBL_USERS where Name LIKE @Name AND excluded=0", 
    new { Name = "%" + TextBox.Text + "%" }
  ).AsList();

else //employee 
  gvTestUsers.DataSource = con.Query<User>(
    @"select * from TBL_USERS where EmployeeNumber = @Emp AND excluded=0", 
    new { Emp = TextBox.Text }
  ).AsList();
```

If EmployeeNumber is alphameric (and you're truly after "contains") and you don't have any way to tell if they typed a name or number, then OR might be the way you have to go:

```
gvTestUsers.DataSource = con.Query<User>(
  @"select * from TBL_USERS where (Name LIKE @X OR EmployeeNumber LIKE @X) AND excluded=0", 
  new { X= "%" + TextBox.Text + "%" }
).AsList();
```

Yep.. that really is all you have to do with Dapper (after creating a `SqlConnection con`) - it handles all the parameters, running the query, retrieving the results, turning them into instances of your `User` class.. (which I'm sure you have, right? If you're using a version of C# that supports records, it's as easy as `record User(string Name, int EmployeeNumber, ...)`)

By comparison, working with datatables is a lot more painful; everything is *stringly* typed, needs casting from object all the time.. Awful

--

However, if you do want to carry on with an **SqlDataAdapter**, it'd look like:

```
var dt = new DataTable;
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from TBL_USERS where (Name LIKE @X OR EmployeeNumber LIKE @X) AND excluded=0", connstringhere);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@X", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "%"+ TextBox.Text + "%";
da.Fill(dt);
gvTestUsers.DataSource = dt;
gvTestUsers.DataBind();
```

If you want name matching to be fuzzy, but emp no. matching to be exact, flip the query to `Name LIKE '%' + @X + '%' OR EmployeeNumber = @X`

<sub>There's some debate around whether dataadapters need disposing or not; Microsoft don't in their example, but some people feel "it's IDisposable, it should be disposed" - adding `using` in front of `var` will do that if you fall into that camp</sub>